# Unit testing using Karma, Jasmine facing issue in Interface based Dependency Injection

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am new to Jasmine, Karma testing. I was facing issue in writing the one of the test cases for service named AuthRealService which injected using an interface name AuthService into component LoginComponent.

here is AuthService interface

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export const AUTH_SERVICE = 'AUTH_SERVICE';
export interface AuthService {
  doAuthenticate(loginUser: any): Observable<any>;
}
```

here is my Real Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SERVICE_URL } from 'src/app/shared/constants/service.constants';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/shared/services/api.service';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthRealService implements AuthService {
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  doAuthenticate(loginUser: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.apiService.post(SERVICE_URL.GET_DIRECT_LOGIN_URL, loginUser);
  }
}
```

Here is Mock Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthMockService implements AuthService {
  doAuthenticate(): Observable<any> {
    const MockSuccessResponse = {
      status: 'SUCCESS',
      data: [
        {
          status: 'Good'
        }
      ]
    };
    return of(MockSuccessResponse).pipe(delay(100));
  }
}
```

The LoginComponent is here

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { APP_CONST } from 'src/app/shared/constants/app.constants';
import {
  COMMON_API_SERVICE,
  CommonApiService
} from 'src/app/shared/services/common-api.service';
import { CommonService } from 'src/app/shared/services/common.service';

import { VoyaPayCloudGlobalState } from 'src/app/shared/store/our-global.store';

import { ToastrService } from '../../../shared/services/toastr.service';
import { AUTH_SERVICE, AuthService } from '../../login/services/auth.service';

const noop = () => {};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  isLabelHidden: boolean;
  errorCount = 0;
   _onTouchedCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;
   _onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;
  public loginFail;
  constructor(
    @Inject(AUTH_SERVICE) private authService: AuthService,
    @Inject(COMMON_API_SERVICE) private commonApiService: CommonApiService,
    private commonService: CommonService,
    private router: Router,
    private toastrService: ToastrService,
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
    vcr: ViewContainerRef
  ) {
    this.toastrService.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(vcr);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //Form intialization is done here
  }

  onSubmit() {
    //implmented after submit functionality here
  }

  login(): void {
  //implemented login functionality here
}
```

here is testing spec file

```
  HttpClient,
  HttpClientModule,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpParams
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { DebugElement, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserModule, By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { AppComponent } from 'src/app/app.component';
import { TextboxComponent } from 'src/app/shared/components/form/voya-textbox/voya-textbox.component';
import { SpinnerComponent } from 'src/app/shared/components/layout/spinner/spinner.component';
import { OurRoutingModule } from 'src/app/shared/modules/our-routing.module';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/shared/services/api.service';
import { CommonApiRealService } from 'src/app/shared/services/common-api-real.service';
import { COMMON_API_SERVICE } from 'src/app/shared/services/common-api.service';
import { CommonService } from 'src/app/shared/services/common.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'src/app/shared/services/toastr.service';
import { AuthRealService } from '../services/auth-real.service';
import { AUTH_SERVICE } from '../services/auth.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

fdescribe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let submitElement: DebugElement;
  let userNameElement: DebugElement;
  let passwordElement: DebugElement;
  let authRealServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<AuthRealService>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const authRealServiceSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('AuthRealService', [
      'doAuthenticate'
    ]);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    
      declarations: [LoginComponent, SpinnerComponent, TextboxComponent],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        OurRoutingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: AuthRealService, useValue: authRealServiceSpyObj },
        ApiService,
        HttpClient,
        { provide: COMMON_API_SERVICE, useClass: CommonApiRealService },
        CommonService,
        Router,
        ToastrService,
        NgxSpinnerService,
        ViewContainerRef
      ]
    });

    //create component test fixture
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);

    authRealServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(AuthRealService);

    //get the test component from the fixture
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });


});
```

In the Above spec file i was trying to `authRealServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(AuthRealService);`
its saying "Type 'AuthRealService' is not assignable to type 'SpyObj'."

I was referring to this solution [How to handle dependency injection into Angular unit test using Jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960557/how-to-handle-dependency-injection-into-angular-unit-test-using-jasmine)

Can anyone please help me out to resolve this issue, early replies appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since `authRealServiceSpy` is of type `SpyObj` when you define it, create a new variable `authRealService` of type `AuthRealService` and then you can do `authRealService = TestBed.inject(AuthRealService);`

```
...
let passwordElement: DebugElement;
let authRealServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<AuthRealService>;
let authRealService: AuthRealService;
.....
authRealService = TestBed.inject(AuthRealService);
```